# Distributed DBSCAN on spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx, dbscan

I'm trying to implement the DBSCAN algorithm on Spark, so I'm following the paper [*A Parallel DBSCAN Algorithm Based on Spark*](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Parallel-DBSCAN-Algorithm-Based-on-Spark-Luo-Luo/4a7b4c47b19f0dc8948f3312cf6e8a54b4081c82).
They propose an algorithm with  4 main steps:

1. Data partition
2. **Computing a local DBSCAN**
3. Merging the data partition
4. Global clustering

So I'm implementing the second step using GraphX, and the pseudocode is something like this:

1. Select an arbitrary point `p` in the current partition
2. Compute the `N_{e}` and if `N_{e} >= minPts` mark p as a core point, otherwise as a noise point.
3. If p is a core point then make a cluster `c` by `p`, adding all the points belonging to cluster `c` to a list for recursive calls.
4. ...

And here my code (I'm aware that it does not work):

```scala
def dataPartition() : Graph[Array[String], Int] = {
    graph.partitionBy(PartitionStrategy.RandomVertexCut)
}

def computingLocalDBSCAN() : Unit = {
    graph = dataPartition() 
   //val neighbors = graph.mapVertices((id, attr) => localDBSCANMap(id, attr))
}

def localDBSCANMap(id: VertexId, attr:Array[String], cluster:Int):Unit = {
    val neighbors = graph.collectNeighbors(EdgeDirection.Out).lookup(id)
    if (neighbors.size >= eps) {
        attr(0) = PointType.Core.toString
        attr(1) = cluster.toString
    } else {
        attr(0) = PointType.Noise.toString
    }

    neighbors.foreach(it => {
        for (item <- it) {
            localDBSCANMap(item._1, item._2, cluster)
        }
    })
}
```

I have multiple questions:

- How could I change the value of one attribute of the vertex? I understand that the vertices are immutable, but I will like to flag the nodes with `Noise`, `Core`, `Border` or `Unclassified`.
- How could I pick a random node inside a partition? Because my problem with the map method is that I have to modify the values at the same time that I'm traversing the graph.
- How could I call a recursive method and modify the attribute values? at the same time?

Comment: I'd start with addressing the problem that `graph.collectNeighbors(EdgeDirection.Out).lookup(id)` called in `mapVertices` cannot work. There are a few (unmaintained) DBSCAN on Spark implementation in the wild - you could use these as an inspiration. Also there are quite a few broad problems here - it could benefit from splitting into separate questions.

Comment: Make sure to benchmark carefully. See the results of Neukirchen, H. (2016). **Survey and Performance Evaluation of DBSCAN Spatial Clustering Implementations for Big Data and High-Performance Computing Paradigms**. - spark does not appear to be fast enough for such problems.

Comment: @user9613318 I'm aware that the code does not work, I don't know how to code those algorithms. I'm been looking for some examples, but the most part doesn't use `GraphX`, or doesn't take care of the complexity.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse thanks for the survey, I'll look at it.

Comment: It wasn't exactly main point. It is not that it doesn't work, it cannot work if you start with this design (the same problem you have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50151804/9613318)). You cannot use nested transformations in Spark.

Comment: Ok, but anyway, it should be a way to solve this kind of problem, right? do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I'd only implement the splitting in Spark, then on each partition run ELKI. It's Java, so easy to call from Spark.